# Debian WPA2-Enterprise (Network-manager) 802.1X no prompt for certificate?

Tags: linux, debian, 802.1, peap

I set up an **access point** (AP) with **PEAP** (Freeradius) **802.1X** authentication and trying to connect the following:

- iOS: Automatically provides the certificate to the onscreen user.
- Windows: Automatically provides the certificate to the onscreen user.
- Linux: No proposed certificate.

My question is simple, do I have to download the certificate from my Linux client (what I would like to avoid) or are there a setting for the network-manager offers me the certificate automatically?

As I am, I am going up a captive portal (operational for apple and windows for now) and I therefore take this opportunity to ask you to pass: what local domain must be hosted (as msftncsi for Windows) for Linux (or redirect traffic with iptables)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. Some NetworkManager frontends will silently fail if presented with an unknown or self-signed certificate (such as the ones usually used with FreeRADIUS). Distributing the certificate to affected clients is probably your best bet.